# C++ NetBeans error on getting string value of an element in a child vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, netbeans, vector

I'm trying to include a vector of pointers in the Element class. So Element objects would contain Child Element.
The error is "Signal received: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)"
The error occurs in this line "string test44 = test333[0]->GetVElement(); "

I'm assuming that either the element object is not pushed back, or the code for getting the child vector is wrong.

Code is posted below. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Element.cpp--------------------

```
Element::Element() {
   this->vLineNo = -1;
   this->vElement = " ";
   this->vContent = " ";
   vector<Element*> temp;
   this->ChildElementVctr = temp;
 }

//4 parameter constructor
 Element::Element(int lineno, string vElement, string vContent,vector<Element*> vVector){
  this->vLineNo = lineno;
  this->vElement = vElement;
  this->vContent = vContent;
  this->ChildElementVctr = vVector;
 } 

void Element::SetChildElementVctr(vector<Element*> ChildElementVctr) {
  this->ChildElementVctr = ChildElementVctr;
}

vector<Element*> Element::GetChildElementVctr() const {
   return ChildElementVctr;
}
```

Main.cpp-----------------

```
vector<Element*> TestVector;

 Element* obj_Element = new Element();
  obj_Element->SetVLineNo(1); // calls setter function of the class Element to assign Line number
  obj_Element->SetVElement("TestElement"); // calls setter function of the     class Element to assign Element tag name
  obj_Element->SetVContent("TestContent");

  Attribute* obj_Attribute = new Attribute();
  obj_Attribute->SetVName("AttributeName");
  obj_Attribute->SetVValue("AttributeValue");
  obj_Element->GetAttributeVctr().push_back(obj_Attribute);

  TestVector.push_back(obj_Element);
  TestVector[0]->GetChildElementVctr().push_back(obj_Element); //push back the elemenet object to the Child Element Vector
  string test11 = TestVector[0]->GetVElement();
  vector<Element*> test333 = TestVector[0]->GetChildElementVctr(); //gets the vector of pointers of Child elements
  string test44 = test333[0]->GetVElement(); //ERROR occurs here
```

Element.h ---

```
class Element {
 public:

  Element();
  Element(int lineno, string vElement,string vContent, vector<Element*> vVector);
  Element(const Element& orig);

   void SetChildElementVctr(vector<Element*> ChildElementVctr);
   vector<Element*> GetChildElementVctr() const;

private:
   int vLineNo ;
   string vElement;
   string vContent;
   vector<Element*> ChildElementVctr;
   vector<Attribute*> AttributeVctr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function

```
vector<Element*> Element::GetChildElementVctr() const {
   return ChildElementVctr;
}
```

returns a vector by value. It copies your member vector. Whatever you do with it, doesn't affect the member of your class. When you `push_back()` elements, you pushing them to the copy. And when you later access the first element of the member vector (or, to be precise, of another copy of it) you end up with an access to the element that does not exist.

To fix the problem, get rid of your accessor function and make vector a public member of the class (now I am asking for downvotes!)

Comment: Thank you Sir. You taught me new thing today.